# Apply filter only on clipped bitmap in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, clipping-mask, crop, filter

I would like to apply a filter in Inkscape only on the clipped part of an object.

I want to apply a filter only on part of a bitmap (shown here as a white square). Typically, I use *Set Clip* to select the part I care about. However, when I apply e.g. *Dark and Glow* after setting the clip, it uses the original object as the source.

How can I apply the filter on the clipped selection? Can this be done with clipping? Or is there another way of cropping in Inkscape?

[image: On the right, I applied "Dark and Glow" after setting the Clip]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inkscape has very limited bitmap image editing tools. But you can apply Edit > Make a Bitmap Copy to your clipped bitmap image. The result hopefully gets SVG effects in the wanted way.

You must set in preferences high enough create bitmap resolution before making one:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly and is excactly what I was looking for. But quick follow up question: I created the example figure using path objects, but I have the same problem. Would I need to convert the path to a bitmap as well, or is there a more elegant option for paths?

Comment: You can subtract unwanted areas from path objects. Path > Difference does the subtraction for closed areas. Or as well you can make an intersection with the wanted area mask path. Every path must be handled separately, you cannot use groups. Open paths must be splitted or converted to closed areas by applying Path > Stroke to path. Learn path operations in the User's Guide.

Comment: @Nico (continued) That's the general method to crop vector shapes if the result must not have hidden parts. If you are going to apply a  filter you can as well make a bitmap copy. You lose nothing because filtering result is finally a bitmap. Save the original vector shape, too because you can need it later.. You can make it invisible in the objects panel.

Comment: Thamk you a lot for the explanation! I am using inkscape mostly for presentations, so all this knowledge is really helpful :)